# Selecting all the pixels in a raster coverage that have a specific pixel value? (in PostGIS raster)

Tags: postgis, raster, select, pixel

I have a land use map in the format of TIFF. I imported this file as a table in PostGIS using raster2pgsql. The land use file has 7 different classes.

[image]

How can I select all those pixels that have the value (class) of 5? The table has only two columns (rid, rast).

Comment: What do you intend to do with the selection? Have you looked at this doc?: https://postgis.net/2014/09/26/tip_count_of_pixel_values/

Comment: I want to select the areas that are lake or river. because in our problem we should avoid those areas.
so I need the location of the pixels that have the value of 5.

Comment: I found ST_PixelOfValue()
But it returns the number of row and column.
I am searching for something that returns me those pixels in a resulting table, a function that clips those pixels with value of 5 and creates a coverage of those ones.

Answer (score 2):

have you tried to polygonize you raster? then you can clip the original raster with the right polygon and you should be good!

Comment: Yes, It is a good idea, but I have a very big data set (for a province). I want to find the fastest way to do it.

Actually, I want to find the lakes to import them as forbidden areas in the rest of the calculations.

Answer (score 1):

You normally would ST_ReClass() the useless values of your raster to nodata (NULL). Then you can convert the withvalue pixel zones to polygons with ST_DumpAsPolygons() or you could intersect them with other polygons with ST_Clip() or ST_Intersection().

Comment: Thanks Pierre your solution is also interesting.
I think it should work fast enough for my case.
Milad Moradi